# Struct Array Dynamic Memory Allocation in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to create an array of structs using dynamic memory allocation. My struct is something along the lines of:

```
typedef struct {
    char data1[200];
    char data2[200];
    char data3[200];
    int data4;
    double data5;
    double data6;
} randomInfo_t;
```

I don't know how many of these structs I need to create, which is why I'm using `malloc()` to dynamically create the array.

There are multiple lines of data stored within a file, similar to a CSV.

Right now, my attempt at creating the array has lead to a segmentation fault, which I suspect is due to the way I'm using `malloc()`:

```
randomInfo_t *stuffArray;
int indexCounter=0;

while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp)) {

    /* some random code here */

    stuffArray[indexCounter] = *(randomInfo_t *)malloc(sizeof(randomInfo_t *));
    assert(stuffArray[indexCounter] != NULL);

    char *readLine = strtok(buffer, " ");

    while(readLine) {
            strcpy(randomArray[indexCounter].data1, readLine);
            
                   etc...
    }

    indexCounter++;

}
```

I've tried debugging it myself, but I have absolutely no clue what I was doing.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

(PS. I know that using a linked list would be a lot easier, and I would prefer to use one as well, but requirements of the code means no linked lists).

Comment: `stuffArray` is a pointer. What is it pointing to?

Comment: Do you want to allocate memory for an array of `randomInfo_t` or do you want to allocate memory for an array of `randomInfo_t *` with each element pointing to a separately allocated `randomInfo_t`? Your code is all wrong, so it is hard to tell which option you are trying to implement.

Comment: In both cases, you can use `realloc` to extend the `stuffArray` memory dynamically.

Comment: @IanAbbott I noticed you have experience with C. Could you please look over my answer and tell me if there is anything that stands out as wrong. Due to the nature of the question it is kind of hard to test it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `stuffArray` is an uninitalized pointer. What you need to do is initalize it and keep track of its current size, like this:

```
// allocate space for 10 pointers to struct
randomInfo_t **stuffArray = malloc(sizeof(randomInfo_t*) * 10); 
int stuffArray_size = 10;
int stuffArray_used = 0;
```

Then when you are allocating space for another struct pointer you do it like this:

```
// if there are more structs than what stuffArray can currently fit realloc
if(indexCounter >= stuffArray_size) {
    stuffArray_size += 10;
    stuffArray = realloc(stuffArray, stuffArray_size * sizeof(randomInfo_t*));
}
stuffArray_used++;
// now we can allocate space for a new struct and point stuffArray[indexCounter] to the newly allocated space
stuffArray[indexCounter] = malloc(sizeof(randomInfo_t));
```

And now when you want to access struct member you have to use `->`.
So this line:

```
strcpy(randomArray[indexCounter].data1, readLine);
```

Now has to be:

```
strcpy(randomArray[indexCounter]->data1, readLine);
```

Also when you are done using the array you have to `free` it.
Like this:

```
// this is where the stuffArray_used comes into play, we don't want to try freeing unallocated memory
for(int i = 0; i < stuffArray_used; i++){
    free(stuffArray[i]);
}
free(stuffArray);
```

Comment: Note that I did write this without testing it because it is kinda tricky to test it with the code you provided but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: Since you wanted a review, it looks OK apart from `if(indexCounter >= size) {` where I think you meant `if(indexCounter >= stuffArray_size) {`. And you need to store the pointer returned by `realloc` back to `stuffArray`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you are attempting to dynamically allocate an array of `randomInfo_t` or an array of `randomInfo_t *` with each element pointing to a `randomInfo_t`.

Assuming you are dynamically allocating an array of `randomInfo_t` you can use `realloc` to gradually increase the size of the array:

```
randomInfo_t *stuffArray=NULL;
int indexCounter=0;

while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp)) {

    /* some random code here */

    randomInfo_t *oldStuffArray = stuffArray; /* In case realloc fails */
    stuffArray = realloc(stuffArray, sizeof(*stuffArray) * (indexCounter + 1));
    if (stuffArray == NULL) {
        /*
         * realloc failed. Take appropriate action here.
         * Note that the memory pointed to by oldStuffArray is still valid.
         */
#if FOO
        /* for example: */
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        free(oldStuffArray);
        exit(1);
#else
        /* or you could use oldStuffArray contents and not read any more: */
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        stuffArray = oldStuffArray;
        break;
#endif
    }

    /* Do stuff with stuffArray[indexCounter] */

    indexCounter++;
}
```